# Set wx.Slider Limit

Tags: python, user-interface, user-controls, slider, wxpython

Is there any way limit a wxpython wx.Slider's control to a point in the middle of the slider? I know I can set the min and max values of the slider, but I want to set up an invisible max or min in the middle.

So if I had a slider that was:

5 |----[]---------| 15

I could stop the user from sliding it past 8.

If this is not possible, is there anyway to get 2 controls/values on one slider? I tried stacking 2 sliders on top of each other, but only the top was selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
self.slider = wx.Slider(panel, value = 0, minValue = 5, maxValue = 15, pos=(10,10), size=(381,-1), style= wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.get_mark, self.slider)

def get_mark(self, event):
    if self.slider.GetValue() >= 8:
        self.slider.SetValue(8)
```

obvisouly have all the other stuff but this is just the widget. What it allows you to do is stop the slider from going past 8. like you said.

There may be a better way, but this is all i could think of.